# Why does wget create "_Conflict" directories?

Tags: wget, recursive

I am trying to back up a club website to a NAS.  Here is a simplified version of the script I am using which illustrates what is happening (without going too deep or accessing protected content):

```
cd /volume1/Backup/
wget -EkKrNpH \
     --output-file=wget.log \
     --domains=imcz.club,sf.wildapricot.org \
     --exclude-domains=webmail.imcz.club \
     --exclude-directories=calendar,Club-Events,External-Events,Sys \
     --ignore-case \
     --level=1 \
     --no-parent \
     --no-proxy \
     --random-wait \
     --reject=ashx,"overlay*" \
     --reject-regex="calendar[@\?].*|Club-Events[@\?].*|External-Events[@\?].*|event-\d+[@\?].*" \
     --rejected-log=wget-rejected.log \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --wait=1 \
     https://imcz.club/
```

When I run it, the following directories are created:

```
 imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts
 imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts_ADMIN_Jun-01-132914-2021_Conflict
 imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts_ADMIN_Jun-01-132917-2021_Conflict
 imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts_ADMIN_Jun-01-132919-2021_Conflict
```

Since I am using -r and --ignore-case *without* --no-clobber, I was expecting the contents of all of these directories to be placed in:

```
imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts
```

However, only the first found font file winds up there, as shown in this logfile excerpt:

```
--2021-06-01 13:28:33--  https://imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
Connecting to imcz.club|34.226.77.200|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 98024 (96K) [application/x-woff]
Saving to: 'imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'
2021-06-01 13:28:34 (233 KB/s) - 'imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' saved [98024/98024]
```

Subsequently found font files wind up in the directories ending in "_Conflict".  Here is an example excerpt from the logfile:

```
--2021-06-01 13:29:12--  https://imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts/opensans-italic-webfont.woff
Connecting to imcz.club|34.226.77.200|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 23188 (23K) [application/x-woff]
Saving to: 'imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts/opensans-italic-webfont.woff'
```

I would try using --debug to understand this better, but the wget version on my NAS was built without debug support.
The website is on a SAAS platform, so I have no control over the inconsistent use of case in addressing the fonts directory. In a browser, any of the fonts can be downloaded from either:

```
imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/fonts
```

or:

```
imcz.club/BuiltTheme/whiteboard_maya_blue.v3.0/1e3b357e/Fonts
```

As a workaround, I tried pre-populating the local "fonts" directory with all of the fonts, hoping that the -r option would then skip downloading them.  However, the "_Conflict" directories were created anyway. Could this be a consequence of --convert-links?
What am I doing wrong, or what have I misunderstood?

Comment: Remove the `--ignore-case and download the copies of the fonts. While `. `wget` could ignore the case when downloading, you would not be able to fully navigate the backup, unless you accessed on a system that ignored the case in the filesystem too.

Comment: Thanks, Eduardo,
Since they are fonts, navigation is not impacted, only the display.  The display is wrong unless I copy all of the fonts from the "_Conflict" directories into the "fonts" directory, because wget fails to correct the paths in the css file where they are used.  Case is unimportant, because I am viewing the result from a Windows PC (--restrict-file-names=windows).  Without --ignore-case, I get many more problems with elements which use inconsistent case on the server.
For the time being, I am just going to skip downloading the fonts, since they are unlikely to change.